# How to import data from large excel file in php?

Tags: php, database, excel, codeigniter

How to import data which is given in the form of excel file and contains column such as say shop name, shop Id, image_url into a database table such that image is first uploaded to amazon simple storage server(S3) and then add eeach row of data in the database table  using PHPEXCEL library?

Comment: Which particular part of that series of requests are you having problems with?

Comment: Actually, first I am downloading image using image_url in my local folder by using copy($image_url,$file_path). And then $input = $this->s3->inputFile($file_path); $url = $this->config->item('s3_uri').'push/images/'.$file_path;  But this process is time consuming and will take lot of time to give results as it first downloaded the image in local folder and then uploaded it to s3 server.

Comment: Ok image download is done now insert data to database is renaming?

Comment: Am I right or you have problem to download image

Comment: Actually it is working fine for small size of data. But when you run it using large data, then it is taking a lot of time. So, I just want to know that is there any other way to do this whole thing in order to reduce the response time?

Comment: Run it as a background task

Comment: Check memory limit and once variable work is done unset it's value

Comment: Unfortuantely there is no other way if you work with excel, large spreadsheets = lots of processing time. Best thing is to run that as a background task or a cron job (depending on requests are handled). Also you could simulate a multithread system by using something like RabbitMQ, that would decrease the processing time, but would increase load on your system drastically.

Comment: Suppose if i want to import .csv file, then how can I do the same?

Comment: I think your script taking much time for execution than its allowed. try to `set_time_limit(600);`  after insert operation ( inside your loop to insert data), it will reset execution time out and set new limit.